# If Then statement not returning as expected

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Where did I mess up this syntax? testname is returning as an empty string. TestType is a Combobox, and TestType.Value in this case is "TE" (confirmed with the debugger)

```
Dim testname    As String
If Not IsNull(TestType.Value) Then (testname = " & TestType.Value & ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised this even ran for you. I can't get it to compile. You can't wrap an entire line in parentheses.

```
If Not IsNull(TestType.value) Then testname = " & TestType.Value & "
```

Comment: I knew it was something dumb. Thanks!

Comment: This is all quite odd. Why would you wish to set testname to the literal `& TestType.Value &`? Surely you want `Then testname = TestType.Value`

Comment: It is very strange in deed...maybe it is being passed to `Eval`?

Comment: @Remou  it is Then testname = TestType.Value. The Ampersands are accidental leftovers from a quick copy paste job within my code.